# Double Linked List Node operator=

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a copy assignment operator for a node in a Doubly Linked List. However, the following code is giving me a stack overflow:

```
template <class DataType>
ListNode<DataType>& ListNode<DataType>::operator=(const ListNode<DataType>& Node)
{
if(this == &Node)
    return *this;
else
{
    if(Child != NULL)
        delete Child;
    if(Parent != NULL)
        delete Parent;

    if(Node.Child != NULL)
    {
        Child = new ListNode<DataType>();
        *Child = *Node.Child;
    }
    else
        Child = NULL;

    if(Node.Parent != NULL)
    {
        Parent = new ListNode<DataType>();
        *Parent = *Node.Parent;
    }
    else
        Parent = NULL;

    _data = Node._data;
}
return *this;
}
```

What would be the standard way of copying a node like this, would I need to use other means (i.e not a copy assignment operator) in order to achieve this? I wanted to avoid doing so as much as possible as it would involve rewriting large amounts of my existing program. This function seems to work fine for a singly linked list, but by adding in copying of the parent pointer it seems to run into problems. I can't seem to pinpoint why, or think of an alternative way to write this function.

Comment: You may want to make a `clear()` function that deletes **all** the nodes currently in your list.  Your destructor could use it and so could this function, where you're currently deleting at most 2 nodes.

Comment: Smells like recursion: `*Child = *Node.Child;`.

Comment: Yep recursion!! you are basically copying the whole linked list. Not just one node.

Answer (score 0):

```
*Parent = *Node.Parent;
```

Will call operator= for the Parent, starting recursion.
BTW in

```
if(Child != NULL)
    delete Child;
```

if is redundant, since delete NULL is a valid operation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the name `parent` to `previous` and `child` to `next`. Just to clarify what they really mean. `Parent` and `child` seem more appropriate for a tree.

```
if(Node.Child != NULL)
{
    Child = new ListNode<DataType>();
    *Child = *Node.Child;
}
```

Remember this will call `ListNode<DataType>::operator=` on the second assignment. Which will call it again and again until the whole chain of children is copied.

Same goes for parent.

```
if(Node.Parent != NULL)
{
    Parent = new ListNode<DataType>();
    *Parent = *Node.Parent;
}
```

So basically you just duplicated the whole list.

---

If you just want to copy one node to another. You should just copy the `value` in the node. Not the actual node. Duplicating the actual Node is not meaningful I think.

For eeample if the link contains `int`s and you want to copy the `5th` member to the `8th` member then you just have to copy the **value of the int** in the node.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. However, if I just copy the value contained within the node, I'm not making a full copy of the node because the node doesn't have the same previous or next pointer as the node being copied.

Comment: @Henri'Henners'Keeble A list is not supposed to have to Nodes which have the same next node or previous node. A list must be a chain. No branches or leaves. Isn't that what you had in mind? Why do you want two nodes to have the same "parent". Then it will be a tree kind of structure. Think about it.

Comment: In that case my problem must lie in my list itself. The operator= for the linked list must have something like `*Head = *param->Head` which is where this operator is being called. Unless I copy over the actual next or previous pointers, I'll run into problems later on.

Comment: @Henri'Henners'Keeble I think the problem is not really about the codeing. I think you should revise what is required from the structure and what is meant by copying. My suggestion was based on just the general idea of lists. Your needs might differ. anyways just try to think about it. Get a piece of paper and draw it out, what is to happen when copying :). That helps a lot with data structures like this.